# Calling an activity with javascript function from fragment

Tags: javascript, android, android-fragments, webview, fragment

I am trying to load another activity after loaded fragment. Toast command is working when i click on any icon on home page webview, but intent is not working. Is there any way to load another activity once i click on the home page icon. Sliding Menu is working perfectly. I placed this code in HOME java class file. Where as Index class file is different. I tried both the ways but its not working. Can you please help me out?

My Piece of Code is:

```
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    String url = "file:///android_asset/www/index.htm";
    webView = (WebView) getView().findViewById(R.id.webviewhome);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new MyBrowser());
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(getActivity()), "Android");
    webView.loadUrl(url);
}


public class WebAppInterface {

    Context mContext;
    WebAppInterface(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }
    @JavascriptInterface
    public void LoadAboutGames() {
        Toast.makeText(mContext, "This is About Games Activity", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @JavascriptInterface
    public void LoadShowInfo() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ShowInfo.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    @JavascriptInterface
    public void LoadAppPhotos() {
        Toast.makeText(mContext, "Hello", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @JavascriptInterface
    public void LoadAppVideos() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Videos.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    @JavascriptInterface
    public void LoadExhibitors() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Exhibitor.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    @JavascriptInterface
    public void LoadMessages() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), AppMessages.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    @JavascriptInterface
    public void LoadTickets() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Tickets.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    @JavascriptInterface
    public void LoadContact() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("file:///android_asset/www/contacts.htm"));
        getActivity().startActivity(intent);

    }

}
```

Comment: try this...  webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());

Comment: After a long struggle i solved my problem 

i just need to use this bit of code and now its working fine as i expected


FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_container, new ShowInfo()).commit();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long struggle i solved my problem i just need to use this bit of code and now its working fine as i expected 
     FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();         fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_container, new ShowInfo()).commit();